# how to upload a file without form using move_uploaded_file function in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have developed one to one chat with ajax and php now please can any one tell me how can I upload a file using `move_uploaded_file` function in php. I am getting file variable `doc = document.getElementById('doc').value;` but files in not uploading and fake path address showing

**JavaScript**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript">
function setfilename(val){
    var fileName = val.substr(val.lastIndexOf("\\")+1, val.length);
    document.getElementById("msg").value = fileName;
    document.getElementById("msg").readOnly = true;
}

function getmsg(){
    document.getElementById("msg").readOnly = false;

    lol = document.getElementById('msg').value;
    doc = document.getElementById('doc').value;

    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("suggestion").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById('msg').value = '';
            var msgList = document.getElementById("mess");
            msgList.scrollTop = msgList.scrollHeight;
            document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;
        }
    }

    if(lol==''){
        xmlhttp.open("GET","chat",true);
        xmlhttp.send(); 
    }else{
        xmlhttp.open("GET","chat?message="+doc,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

**html**

```
<div id="chat_box" class="chat_window">
    <div class="top_menu">
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="button close"></div>
            <div class="button minimize"></div>
            <div class="button maximize"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="title">Messaging about order-id: ODR-46</div>
    </div>

    <div id="your_div">
        <ul class="messages" id="mess" style="overflow:scroll;" >
            <li id="suggestion"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom_wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="message_input_wrapper">
            <input class="message_input" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('send').click()" id="msg" placeholder="Type your message here..." />
        </div>
        <a id="send" onclick="return getmsg();">
            <input type="file" onchange="setfilename(this.value);" id="doc">
            <div class="send_message">
            <div class="icon"></div>
            <div class="text" >Send</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="message_template">
    <div class="avatar"></div>
    <div class="text_wrapper">
        <div class="text"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**php code**

```
// move_uploaded_file(get variable from javascript that is doc,'document/');
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `move_uploaded_file`?

Comment: You appear to be trying to do an AJAX upload of files. What you're doing likely won't work. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications for info on HTML5's file handling.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to upload file without using move_uploaded_file function,use this instead:You can use this

> http://fineuploader.com/

This uploads the files in a directory you specify using chunking.